# What are the character encodings UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 rules

Tags: character-encoding

I was wondering is there an article that discusses the rules for the character encodings UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1?

Can someone also point me to the rules of other character encodings as well?

Comment: The algorithms for encoding/decoding UTF-8 can be found in [RFC 3629](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/utf-8/info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html - it will clear any questions you have about Unicode, Encoding etc.

**Edit:** B.T.W., I'm not so clear about what you mean by "rules", but this article should clear any questions you have about what `UTF-8` and `ISO-8859-1` are.

Comment: You was half a second faster than me! :)

Comment: @RonK I want to know the guideline of dealing with bad characters.

Comment: @UTF-8: What do you mean by bad characters? Do you refer to Unicode codepoints that are mapped in `UTF-8` but not in `ISO-8859-1`? 
B.T.W., which programing language do you use?

Comment: @RonK I use php, I mean malformed encodings

Comment: @UTF-8: Can you add examples - I don't understand what you mean by malformed encodings

Comment: for example when you code in the Unicode Character 'REGISTERED SIGN' (U+00AE) wrong \xC2 instead of \xC2\xAE

Comment: Who codes it? Is it something you receive as input from end user/external system?
Or is it something you want to input in your code directly?

Comment: lets say a user enters it into a comment like I just did and I then try to evaluate it with some type of code.

Comment: Well, I'm not that familiar with `PHP`, so I don't know how to answer you correctly, but lets take Java as an example:
If I read the input as a String - Java knows to handle it. If I get it as a `byte[]` and need to convert it to a `String` - I need to know which `encoding` to use - so I think you should post a new question specifically about `PHP` and handling character user input in different encodings.
I found two `PHP` links which I assume you read already - but if not, they might help:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/xml.encoding.php

Answer (score 0):

[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) on Wikipedia is a good place to start.